# Error when running an app using the runApp('App.R')

Tags: r, shiny, run-app

I have a problem running my Shiny App using the `runApp()` button in R. I recieve the error message:

```
Error in ..stacktraceon..({ : object '.' not found
```

I can run the app if I just use `ctrl+A` and then `ctrl+enter` which uses the `shinyApp(ui, server)` function instead. Every function in the application works fine when I run it this way.
The problem with running the app this way is that I can't publish the application.

This problem only occurs when running a specific app.
I've found someone with a similar problem here:

```
https://github.com/Coorsaa/shinyMlr/issues/126
```

Puy the post ends by Coorsaa saying that the problem should be fixed now. Anyone know how to fix this?

Do you need me to post the code for the app here? -or does the problem have something to do with R or Shiny?

Comment: Most likely you have a "." in front of a comment or executable line in your code.  You need to remove that "." in your code.  It would be best to post your code, if you need someone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

YBS had the answer.

"Most likely you have a "." in front of a comment or executable line in your code. You need to remove that "." in your code. It would be best to post your code, if you need someone to help you."

This was exactly what I found infront of one of my comments.
Thanks! I didn't notice that at all.